# How can I join multiple models in Django into a virtual table?

Tags: python, django

If I have 3 models, like:

```py
class Cow(models.Model):
    name =
    number_of_eyes =
    number_of_feet =
    color =

class Pig(models.Model):
    name =
    number_of_eyes = 
    number_of_feet =
    intelligence = 
    
class Horse(models.Model):
    name =
    number_of_eyes =
    number_of_hooves = 
    weight_capacity =
    speed =
```

And I'm interested in making a single `Livestock` table in my template that has instances of all 3, but I'm only interested in these columns that all 3 models have:

- name
- number_of_eyes
- number_of_feet (number_of_hooves if Horse)

And we can ignore all other columns.

How can I join them into a single queryset?

The end goal is to get a single virtual table (queryset) that I can do a few other operations on (filter, order_by, slice), and then return the data in just those columns.

Is this possible in the Django ORM?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can do this with a [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#union).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this can also be done using a `Union`, as suggested by Nick ODell:

```py
from django.db.models import F

Cow.objects.filter(...).union(
  Pig.objects.filter(...), 
  Horse.objects.filter(...).annotate(number_of_feet=F("number_of_hooves"))
).values('name', 'number_of_eyes', 'number_of_feet').order_by('name')[:3]
```

Unfortunately you can't filter on the resulting queryset after the union, so you need to filter each queryset before the union, but other than that, everything seems to work in my quick test.

From what I understand, the difference here from MojixCoder's suggestion of using `ContentType` is that you don't need to maintain a separate definition of this virtual table in your Django models module. In some cases, that can be an advantage, as you don't need to keep the module updated when you get new models you want to include in your query, but in other cases, it can be a disadvantage, because my way has a lot of typing every time you want to use this query, whereas in MojixCoder's example, you define it once, and your queries would be much shorter.

Edit: Using `annotate` and `union` can result in the [results being out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59827016/6423456). Special care must be taken to ensure this doesn't happen

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

1. using `itertools.chain`:

   ```
   from itertools import chain


   cows = Cow.objects.all()
   pigs = Pig.objects.all()
   horses = Horse.objects.all()

   livestock_list = sorted(
       chain(cows, pigs, horses), 
       key=lambda livestock: livestock.created_at, reverse=True)
   )
   ```
2. using `contenttypes`:

   ```
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


   class Livestock(models.Model):
       content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
       object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
       content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
       created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

       class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created']
   ```

   Now you can query `Livestock` model like any other model in `Django`, but you can have a foreign key that can refers to n models. that's what `contenttypes` do.

   `Livestock.content_object` gives you what you want in your case it can be `Cow`, `Pig` or `Horse`.

   Just remember to add objects to `Livestock` model after you create horse, etc instances. you need to add them in 2 models actually. you can do it with signals.

I think the second solution is better.

Comment: The problem with using `itertools.chain` is that you're pulling ALL the records from the database, having Python sort them, and then having Python process them (filter them and slice them), which works, but isn't efficient. I have a lot of records in the database, and the first rule of using an ORM is not to make Python do any processing that you can tell the database to do. I'll have to do a bit of reading on `ContentType` to get a better understanding of what's going on in your example there. Thanks

Comment: yeah as I said `contenttypes` framework is a better solution.